# Factorial calculation between two integers

Tags: erlang

The function is supposed to calculate the sum of the integers between 2 integers N and M where N <= M.

```
sum(N, M) ->
    if
        N+1 =< M -> N + sum((N+1), M);
        N =< M -> N;
        N > M -> 'N must be <= M'
    end.
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can I put the second statement inside the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments and proposition

```
-module (ex).

-compile([export_all]).

%% some comments on your proposal
sum1(N, M) ->
    if  %% if statement is not very popular in Erlang since it is not realy an if like in java or C
        N+1 =< M -> N + sum1((N+1), M);
        N =< M -> N;
        N > M -> 'N must be <= M' %% don't do this, it creates useless atoms that are limited
                                  %% in number and cannot be destroyed during the VM life
    end.


%% second solution, tail recursive
sum2(N,M) when N > M -> {error,"N must be <= M"}; %% instead use a guard an return a tuple with
                                                  %% standard atom + a string for the reason
sum2(N,M) -> sum2(N,M,0). %% use an accumulator to create a tail recursive function
                          %% not really important for this example but it is a good usage
                          %% to avoid stack overflow :o)

sum2(M,M,R) -> M+R;
sum2(N,M,R) -> sum2(N+1,M,R+N).  %% like this it is tail recursive.


%% third solution, without recursion: don't use recursive function if it is not necessary
sum3(M,M) -> M;
sum3(0,M) -> sum3(1,M);
sum3(N,M) when N =< M ->  %% don't be defensive unless your function is likely subject to
                          %% receive bad argument from user intreface
    (M*(M+1)-(N-1)*N) div 2.
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the lengthy response but the answer above had exactly what I had asked for. I have saved your answer for future references. I appreciate it.

Comment: @ A23, take care that the solution proposed by Marutha is very concise, but it generates an intermediate list which can be time and memory consuming if the difference between the 2 integers is big. (for example if the difference is over 100 000 000 on my PC it crashes the Virtual Machine after some minutes trying to generate the list).

Comment: After some work, your solution worked out for the best

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
sum(N, M) when N > M ->
    {error, 'N must be <= M'};
sum(N, M) ->
    List = lists:seq(N, M),
    lists:foldl(fun(X, Sum) -> X + Sum end, 0, List).
```

It is always better to use tail recursions, and guard for validating something in a best practice.

Comment: Rather than using `lists:foldl/3` here you should use `lists:sum/1`.

Comment: Thanks, missed out that.. :(